# How do I isolate consecutive pixels of certain length in photoshp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to isolate pixels that are adjacent to each other horizontally, vertically, or diagonally(preferably with specified length). The image I'm working with has no known pattern ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAep.png)). Is there a way to either remove lone pixels or highlight lines of pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Answers has been posted here:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-to-remove-detect-lone-pixels/m-p/10971705?page=1#M313346

```
• duplicate the Layer thrice,

• move one copy 1 px to the right,

• aother 1 px down, 

• convert the three Layers to a Smart Object, 

• Layer > Smart Objects > Stack Mode > Median, 

• Filter > Other > Minimum aith 1px and Roundness, 

• set the Smart Object’s Blend Mode to Screen.
```

```
If you have black(gray\color) pixels and absolute white backgound then you can do this.

Make two copies of the original layer.



Apply to one of the copies Custom Filter

0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
scale: 8 offset: 0



Using magic wand with

tol = 0, antial = off, cont = off

select white (255,255,255) on this layer.
If it's hard to find white, find a single pixel on the original, it will definitely turn white.



Turn off \ delete this layer. Switch to another copy. Fill the selection with white.
You can check the result by putting the layer to Difference blend mode or turning layer on\off.


Pixels at the very edges are not deleted. It is necessary to expand the canvas by 1 pixel at least with white filling.



UPD. To increase accuracy, you can replace in filter 1 with 256, and in scale 8 with 2048.
```